# debugging unauthorized sections of website with xdebug

Tags: php, laravel-4, phpstorm, xdebug

after a couple of days I finally installed xdebug 2.2.5 and configured to work with phpStorm, but now I have the first doubt. The php application is created with laravel 4.2 having the following structure:

1. **localhost/cool-app/login**: an user authentication form
2. **localhost/cool-app**: dashboard for authenticated user
3. **localhost/cool-app/foo**: another section for authenticated user

Suppose that `localhost/cool-app/foo` calls some functions that consumes a lot of resources like ram and time. So, I would like to debug this part of the application, but this section is for an authenticated user, then when I tried to debug the specific controller for *localhost/cool-app/foo*, the debugger never get into it because the application redirects the request to /login.  (Looks like the debugger is taken as a guest user)

So, how do you deal with this when you need to debug sections of an application that are filtered only for a specific access? Maybe you will suggest me to disable the authentication process, but I do not have privileges to change the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can listen to debug connections in PHPStorm and you can start a debug session from your browser.

First start listening for debug connections in PHPStorm:

[image: PHPStorm Listen To Debug Connections]

Then generate debug bookmarklets [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/). They're needed to start the debug session from your browser. Drag them to your Bookmarks Bar for easy access:

[image]

Then fire up the app in your browser and navigate to the URL you want to test (if you need to access a protected area then you'll need to login, and in doing so you'll create the session needed for debugging). When you want to start debugging just click on the `Debug this page` bookmarklet and you should be good to go.

Also make sure you have enabled `xdebug.remote_enable=1` in your `php.ini` file and that `xdebug.remote_port` matches the one in your PHPStorm configuration (by default it should `9000`).

### EDIT

To use the profiler do the following. Make sure you have configured the xdebug profiler settings in `php.ini`:

```
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /path/to/profiler/output
```

In the browser go to the page you want to profile and click on `Start profiler` and then refreash the page, then click on `Stop profiler`. You should now have a `cachegrind` file in the directory you specififed for `profiler_output_dir`.

To analize the `cachegrind` files with PHPStorm you just need to go to `Tool > Analyze Xdebug Profiler Snapshot...`:

[image]

You can also use [KCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) for Linux or [WinCacheGrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/) for Windows to analyze the profiler snapshots.

Be aware that the xdebug profiler can slow down page execution while collecting data, so don't be alarmed if the application is slower while the profiler is active.

Comment: I read a little bit about "bookmarklets", but my poor english did not help me to understand the concept. But, after see your answer now is clarify. Thank you so much.

Comment: Bogdan, one little question. With bookmarklets am I able to generate the profiler log?

Comment: Yes you can. I've updated my answer with instructions for using the profiler.

Comment: Well, I would like to give you more upvotes. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Seaching for references I found a very helpful video from laracast website:

- https://laracasts.com/series/how-to-be-awesome-in-phpstorm/episodes/20

This video show how to solve specifically my question. Thank you so muc.